# error: conversion to non scalar type from int to template

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, c++17

For an assignement, we have to implement eg a stack with templates. But I get an error which I can't really make any sense of:

```
error: conversion from ‘shared_ptr<Seq_Node<int>>’ to non-scalar type ‘shared_ptr<Seq_Node<ProjectAlpha::T>>’ requested
   12 |     Seq_NodePtr front = std::make_shared<Seq_Node<T>>(data);
```

(Note `ProjectAlpha` is the Namespace we have to use)

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "ProjektAlpha/stack.hpp"
#include <memory>

namespace ProjectAlpha {
  template<class T> Stack<T>::Stack() :
  num_elements(0),
  head(nullptr)
  {  
  }
  template<class T> void Stack<T>::insert(T& data) {
    Seq_NodePtr front = std::make_shared<Seq_Node<T>>(data);
    this->num_elements++;
    front->next = this->head->next;
    this->head->next = front;
  };
  
  template<class T> void Stack<T>::remove() {
    num_elements--;
    //TODO

  }
  template<class T> size_t Stack<T>::size() {
    return num_elements;
    //TODO
  }
  template<class T> T& Stack<T>::top() {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "ProjektAlpha/seq_node.hpp"

namespace ProjectAlpha {

  template<class T> Seq_Node<T>::Seq_Node(T& data) :
    data_(data),
    next(nullptr)
    //prev(nullptr)
  {

  };
  
}
```

```cpp
#include "ProjektAlpha/stack.hpp"

int main () {
  ProjectAlpha::Stack<int> *test = new ProjectAlpha::Stack<int>();
  delete test;
}
```

The last bit is what I want to compile as a first test.

Comment: Where is the definition of `Seq_NodePtr`?

Comment: It is in seq_node.hpp (which i did not upload since there is little code), and is the following: typedef std::shared_ptr<Seq_Node<class T>> Seq_NodePtr;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `Seq_NodePtr` is wrong.

> ```
> typedef std::shared_ptr<Seq_Node<class T>> Seq_NodePtr;
>                                    ^
> ```

`class T` is wrong to use in this typedef. It is forward declaring a separate class named `T` in the containing namespace (hence why the error message mentions `ProjectAlpha::T`).

`int` and `ProjectAlpha::T` are unrelated types, so `Seq_Node<int>` and `Seq_Node<ProjectAlpha::T>` are also unrelated types, hence the error.

If the typedef were nested inside the `Stack` class then you could just drop the `class` to use `Stack`'s own `T` template argument instead.

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Seq_Node<T>> Seq_NodePtr;
};
```

Otherwise, consider changing `typedef` to `using` so you can give `Seq_NodePtr` its own template argument, eg:

```
template <typename T>
using Seq_NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Seq_Node<T>>;
```

And then change `Seq_NodePtr front = ...` to `Seq_NodePtr<T> front = ...`.

Or, you could just use `auto front = ...` instead.